# queue up function callbacks

Tags: javascript, callback

A few different functions are called when an event happens. For simplicity sake, let's say I have two different analytics tracking requests sent out. They each have a callback function to redirect a visitor after the response is received.

```
function analytics(event,callback){
    // send analytics event;
    if (callback) callback();
}

function analytics2(event,callback){
    // send analytics2 event;
    if (callback) callback();
}
```

The callback function is usually:

`If: tracking response is received from remote server`

`Then: redirect to URL`

```
$("a").click(function(){
    analytics(
        'clicked on ' + $(this).attr('id'),
        function(){
            location.assign($(this).attr('href'));
        }
    );

    analytics2(
        'clicked on ' + $(this).attr('id'),
        function(){
            location.assign($(this).attr('href'));
        }
    );
});
```

**Question:** What's the best way to queue up these callbacks, so I wait for all callback functions to be ready before redirecting? As it's setup now, whenever *the first* callback runs the visitor is redirected -- without ever knowing if the server recieved the `analytics2()` function.

I've seen some sites use their own queue system, I just have no idea how this is implemented.

Any suggestions/thoughts?

Should I set `analytics2()` as the callback for `anlaytics()`? But then if I end up not running `analytics()` then `analytics2()` would never run. Ideally, I'd like to have a more organized approach.

Comment: Try [promises](http://promisesaplus.com/)!

Comment: Suppose we can get the two analytics to run at the same time, are you looking to use the recommended redirect from the first one that receives a response or are you planning to compare results before making a redirect decision?

Comment: I don't think i'll be comparing anything. I'd just need to make sure both  responses are received, and most likely will redirect to the same place for all of these functions.

Comment: Check out the jQuery `.deferred()` and `.then()` methods. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Deferred/

Comment: so where's the call to analytics2?

Answer (score 2):

```
$.when(analytics(), analytics2()).done(function(a1Result, a2Result){
    ... make decisions based on a1Result and a2Result
});
```

This is jQuery's version of `promises`, allowing you to make two async calls and defer any decisions until they have both completed.